# Discount on grouped product in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am using magento 2.3.5. and I created one group product with a combine of 3 simple products. now I want to give an offer of a group product. so how I can create the promotion for the group product?

Comment: what kind of promotion do you need? catalog promotion? or a shopping cart promotion?

Comment: any promotion will be ok

Answer (score 0):

**Case A - your products are not visible individually** - Basically you could build a cart rule (for example) and restrict the conditions in the **'Conditions'** and **'Actions'** sections so that they apply to only the child products given the fact that you know which are the SKUs of the child products.

I tried this on a clean Magento Open source 2.4.1 with sample data:
[image]

**Case B - your products are visible individually** - Well here things get complicated as you don't have coverage with default Magento capabilities. When you add the grouped product to cart, the collection of simple products is added in the quote items table and there is no reference to the 'parent' product. What I suggest as a workaround is to **create your composite product as a bundle** (a particular case of bundle) where your options contain each only one product. This way, you can create the rule with conditions 'SKU(Parent only)':

[image]

The inconvenience in the second approach is that obviously this is not a grouped product per se aaaand in the frontend you have this additional 'Customize and Add to Cart' click leading to the bundle product options.

Comment: it's giving a discount on the whole cart price. it's including if I add one product separately which I already added in the group product.  I want, only on group product. It should exclude the other product.

Comment: yes, indeed. hmm i didn't consider the fact that your children products are visible also. in a scenario where they would be not visible individually, the above solution would be enough.

Comment: ok, let's see what can be done :)

Comment: well, found a workaround for your problem, please check my updates on my answer above.

Comment: actually, I cant go with bundle product, because it creates a separate SKU and in the cart also added as same. I need to add the product same as the group product added.

Comment: if you know of any extension which can solve my issue... please suggest that also.

Comment: hi there, unfortunately I don't know any extension for this, but you can check the magento marketplace. in the meantime, there is still a workaround which might work but it depends on what you do with the products SKUs after the order is placed (like sending order to ERP based on skus). so my idea is that you duplicate the products that need to be grouped together and set them as 'not visible individually' and use the initial approach from my answer. ofc, it depends if duplication of these products can be used for the reasons mentioned above.